# path wildcards in npm tasks (windows vs. linux)

Tags: node.js, linux, jenkins, wildcard, postcss

I am having an issue with the following npm task that runs autoprefixer against a wildcard path:

```
"css:autoprefix": "postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"Last 2 versions\" -r src/frontend/app/**/*.css"
```

The command works perfectly on windows but on my linux (jenkins build server, the css is not getting prefixed. Is it possible that linux isn't understanding the `**/*.css` in the command?

Comment: Could be tagged `npm` and `npm-scripts`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible that linux isn't understanding the **/*.css in the command?

You are exactly right.

**This should work:**

```
"css:autoprefix": "postcss -u autoprefixer --autoprefixer.browsers \"Last 2 versions\" -r \"src/frontend/app/**/*.css\""
```

**Why this works:**

Windows doesn't support globs at all, so it passes `**/*.css` directly to postcss, which expands it correctly.

Linux supports globs, but many distributions do not support the globstar (`**`) by default. The Linux shell attempts to expand the glob, but parses `**` to mean `*`. That doesn't correctly expand it. By wrapping the glob in quotes, the glob will always be passed directly to postcss, which can expand it correctly.